# Java Generics - What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: java, generics

can anyone tell me why the put is giving me an error?

```
static HashMap<Class, ? extends BaseSystem> systems;

public <T extends BaseSystem> EntityManager()//constructor
{
    systems=new HashMap<Class, T>();
} 

public static <T extends BaseSystem> void addSystem(Class c, T system)//store a system for later reference
{
    systems.put(c, system);
}
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: I don't think it is the issue here - but why are you initializing an *static* variable in a constructor? It will reset `systems` for each instance of your class you generate. If this is the behavior you want, you want `systems` to be an *instance variable* and not a *class variable*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most likely problem is that the T in the first method and the T in the second method are not automagically considered the same.  In other works you have two different types which both extends BaseSystem but could be unrelated.

You need to define T once on the class and use it consistently or just use BaseSystem and not use generics.

BTW: On a more basic level, don't confuse static initialisation and instance intialisation.  If you are setting a static field in a constructor you have a design issue.

Is there any relationship between the class and the `T` system?

Comment: Im building an ES, or at least trying to. The Class param is the key for querying which system the component belongs to. The HashMap is a collection of all the systems the EntityManager is in charge of coordinating. When each system extends the BaseSystem, is there any need to template this, or can i just say its a collection of BaseSystem and not worry about it? Its been a while since ive used collections storing multiple subclasses.

Comment: Also, how do you define T for the class? I suspect this is the error im getting, as its saying something about failure to match T #1 to T

Comment: You can only define a instance `T` in the class definition for non-static members.  In your case I would make them all `BaseSystem`.

Comment: Trying to use generics everywhere can lead to a mess of really cryptic error messages. ;)